# Using 'should' in function names

Tags: semantics

This is a question with no definite answer so apologies if I posted this wrongly however at my place of work alot of the code I see written by our developers have function names with the keyword 'should', must I add they base this on 'should' and 'should not'. From a point of semantics, whats your view on this? I've mentioned before that I don't believe this should be used because it has too many possibilities (where does it end) however they insist its a good practice.

Example use;

```
$this->it_should_render_template_partially($params);

$this->it_should_show_module_parameters($params);

$this->it_should_not_return_module_parameters($params);
```

I am curious on others thoughts. Just to add, this is production code and not unit tests.

Comment: What does it do if it doesn't? Every function should do what it's supposed to do... That aside, I'm not sure if this would belong here, Programmers.SE, or nowhere.

Comment: It's a pretty clear naming convention for tests....

Comment: @theodox I'd agree for testing however, this is production code.

Comment: @NickT well I was unsure where to post this is. Pretty blunt answer though.

Answer (score 1):

While I like long, descriptive, names, I don't like redundancy. When I read the documentation of a function, I expect it to do what it is supposed to do. Yes, functions are written by humans that make a lot of mistakes, so they can have bugs, which means they do not behave as intended. But this is implied when one uses a function. We hope that out functions do what they should (and we try to make sure that is the case using tests). But specifying the should part in the name of a function is just redundant, which is, in my opinion, a bad practice, as it results in longer names, harder to read/write.